# ¿Cómo solucionar los errores en los comando mkdir, rmdir y touch para crear y eliminar archivos desde la terminal de Git Bash en windows 10?

Tags: git-bash

Estoy teniendo problemas para crear y eliminar archivos desde la terminal de Git Bash en windows 10. Solo puedo crear carpetas.

No se si alguien sabe como solucionarlo, pero llevo dos dias buscando info y no encuentro. Adjunto imagen.

Desde ya muchas gracias!

```
   user@jotapc2 MINGW64 ~/Documents/WorkingDirectory/prueba
$ ls
carpeta1/  mi-archivo.txt

user@jotapc2 MINGW64 ~/Documents/WorkingDirectory/prueba
$ rmdir carpeta1/
rmdir: failed to remove 'carpeta1/': Permission denied

user@jotapc2 MINGW64 ~/Documents/WorkingDirectory/prueba
$ rm mi-archivo.txt
rm: cannot remove 'mi-archivo.txt': Permission denied

user@jotapc2 MINGW64 ~/Documents/WorkingDirectory/prueba
$ touch index.html
touch: cannot touch 'index.html': No such file or directory

user@jotapc2 MINGW64 ~/Documents/WorkingDirectory/prueba
$ rm -r mi-archivo.txt
rm: cannot remove 'mi-archivo.txt': Permission denied

user@jotapc2 MINGW64 ~/Documents/WorkingDirectory/prueba
$
```

Comment: Hola Javier, Hola xx, bienvenido, tanto el código como los mensajes de error, deben estar en formato texto, no en imágenes, te sugiero que edites tu pregunta y la adaptes a los requerimientos del sitio, de esa forma lograrás que sea mejor recibida y evitarás recibir votos negativos, puedes ver [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para mas info.

Comment: Intentaste ejecutando el bash como administrador??

Answer (score 0):

si el directorio no está vacío no te dejará eliminarlo con ese comando. Ahora, en el caso del fichero de texto estás cometiendo un error ya que lo intentas eliminar con el comando de eliminar directorios, para poder hacerlo puedes utilizar `rm nombre_archivo.extension` ó `rm -r nombre_archivo.extension`.

Aquí te dejaré esto para que revices el [tema de eliminar ficheros y directorios en Windows](https://www.freecodecamp.org/espanol/news/cmd-eleminar-carpeta-como-eliminar-archivos-y-carpeta-en-windows/)

Comment: hice lo que me dijiste, pero sigo igual como verás en el código editado.

Comment: yo probé en mi `git bash` los comandos que habías puesto inicialmente y realicé las operaciones sin problema alguno, por supuesto, sustituyendo el comando de eliminar directorios por el que te dije para eliminar un fichero.

Comment: Hola William, si la verdad no se si es un tema de mi windows, mi pc. Porque no encuentro alguien mas con mi problema.